# YAML code to create multiple VPC using count in AWS cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I'm new to CloudFormation and want to create a template using YAML. I need to figure out is there any way we can create multiple VPCs using UserInput.
As of now, I've used the following code:

```
  Parameters:
      EnvironmentName:
        Description: An environment name that is prefixed to resource names
        Type: String
    
    vpcCIDR1:
      Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
      Type: String
      Default: 10.3.0.0/16
    vpcCIDR2:
      Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
      Type: String
      Default: 10.4.0.0/16
Resources:
  VPC1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref vpcCIDR1
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
  VPC2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref vpcCIDR2
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
```

Instead of writing the same code again, I need the code to take user input for the VPCs count and create the VPCs according to the user input.

I've found the [Count](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-macros/blob/master/Count/src/index.py) but when I use !Ref to pass parameter it is not working, it only works when I pass Count: 2 or any numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that if you develop your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html). There are no loops nor any complex processing of user input in CloudFormation. But with macro, you can program any logic you want. Alternatively, you could also use [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html), if you don't want macros.

Comment: I did search for macro but did not find any related topics which can help me to create multiple VPCs using user input.

Comment: @ShritejMurmadkar you have to develop it your self. Start by reading documentation, do examples given then, and learn how to develop macros.

Comment: I'm using Count function: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-macros/blob/master/Count/src/index.py
but when I'm trying to pass the user input !Ref to the count parameter it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that CloudFormation doesn't has any function to create multiple resources using loops. CloudFormation has no loops.

You can however declare your resources and you can use `Condition` in CloudFormation Template along with `Intrinsic Conditional Functions`. This is the way people have been doing.

You can read more about using `Condition` in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html).
You can read more about using `Intrinsic Conditional Functions` in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html).

```yaml
Parameters:
    EnvironmentName:
      Description: An environment name that is prefixed to resource names
      Type: String
  vpcCIDR1:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 10.3.0.0/16
  vpcCIDR2:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 10.4.0.0/16
  CreateVpc1:
    Type: String
    Default: false
    AllowedValues:
      - true
      - false
  CreateVpc2:
    Type: String
    Default: false
    AllowedValues:
      - true
      - false

Conditions:
  BooleanCreateVpc1: !Equals [ !Ref CreateVpc1, true ]
  BooleanCreateVpc2: !Equals [ !Ref CreateVpc2, true ]

Resources:
  VPC1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Condition: BooleanCreateVpc1
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref vpcCIDR1
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
  VPC2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Condition: BooleanCreateVpc1
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref vpcCIDR2
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
```

Comment: Hi Shivam, Thanks for the response, it worked for me but it is again a manual method for writing code multiple times, I wanted the method which would help me to create multiple resources using user input.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a rudimentary bash script like this (I haven't fully tested the deployment and you'll need to modify your file name etc), but something like this would be a starting point:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -n1 -r -p "Would you like to create another VPC: [y]es|[n]o"; do
  case $REPLY in
    y)  echo
        echo "Enter a VPC name: "
        read vpcName
        echo
        echo "Enter a VPC CIDR: "
        read vpcCIDR
        echo
        echo "Enter a VPC Environment: "
        read Environment
        echo
        echo "Creating VPC with:
        VPC Name: $vpcName
        VPC CIDR: $vpcCIDR
        VPC Environment: $Environment"
        echo
        aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myteststack --template-body file://sampletemplate.json \
        --parameters ParameterKey=vpcCIDR,ParameterValue=$vpcCIDR \
        ParameterKey=vpcName,ParameterValue=$vpcName \
        ParameterKey=Environment,ParameterValue=$Environment
        ;;

    n)  echo
        echo "Nothing further to do, good bye!"
        exit;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: How can I use this in cloud formation?